# detailtableview controller to push the image from tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

hi I'm trying to view the image and description form tableview to detailviewcontroller  but not I'm not able get it. I'm fetching the image form server i have stored the image url and using the json and php coding  I'm getting the image url using the NSURLConnectionDelegate viewing the images and description in tableview .

i have trying many ways to view those images in the tableview but getting the images.

detailview controller.h file coding

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "image.h"
@class image;
@interface viewdetailpoliticalViewController : UIViewController<NSURLConnectionDelegate>
{
  NSURLConnection *connection;
}


    @property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *value;
    @property (strong,nonatomic) UIImage *imm;

    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageview;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *dcp
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableData *responseData;

 -(void)setDataSource:(image *)inImageOb;
  @end
```

this is my detailview controller.m file coding

```
  #import "viewdetailpoliticalViewController.h"
  #import "image.h"
  @interface viewdetailpoliticalViewController ()

  @end

  @implementation viewdetailpoliticalViewController
  @synthesize imageview,dcp;
  @synthesize value,imm;

 - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
  {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
   if (self) {
      // Custom initialization
  }
     return self;
  }

  - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.imageview.image = self.imm;
    self.dcp.text = self.value;
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
 }

 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
   [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


 -(void)setDataSource:(image *)inImageOb
 {
   self.value = inImageOb.desp;


   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:inImageOb.img];
   NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
   connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
   self.responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

 }


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data;
{
     [self.responseData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection;
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:self.responseData];
    self.imm = image;
}


@end
```

this is my tableview controller m file coding:

```
   - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Detailsegue" sender:indexPath];
     }
   - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
        if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Detailsegue"]) {

    viewdetailpoliticalViewController *detailvc = (viewdetailpoliticalViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;

     NSIndexPath *indexPath =[self.mytableview indexPathForSelectedRow];

    [detailvc setDataSource:[imgevery objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];


  }
}
```

this is code i have used to fetch the datas using json

```
  -(void) retrieveData
{
   NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:getDataURL];
   NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

   json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];



   imgevery =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (int i=0; i<json.count; i++) {

    NSString * dd = [[json objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"imgp"];
    NSString * plae =[[json objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"disp"];
    image *myimg =[[image alloc]initWithimg:dd anddesp:plae];

    [imgevery addObject:myimg];

 }

  [self.mytableview reloadData];

}
```

this is the code i have used for the tableview cell

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{

   return 1;
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return imgevery.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *cellIdentifier =@"Cell";

imgpoliticalCell *cell =(imgpoliticalCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (cell== nil) {


    cell = [[imgpoliticalCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}
[cell setDataSource:[imgevery objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

 // cell.thumbImageView.image = _img;


   return cell;
 }
```

Comment: what is here about setDataSource:??

Comment: using that setdatasource im fetching the images form the database

Comment: k Could you explain bit more whether its passing or not to detilvc ? what is o/p you getting

Comment: no sir its no passing im getting a black screen in detilvc

Comment: using that setdatasoucre only im fetching the images and description in table view i have tried in the detailview samething

Comment: imagevery is a mutable array which fetch the datas form database using json

Comment: above in i have edited the codes pls check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem the problem is u passing data through Setimage Source

you set image in viewDidload itself after -(void)setDataSource:(image *)inImageOb only viewDidload () will run but you assigned image to imageview in viewDidLoad() itself

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.imageview.image = self.imm;
    self.dcp.text = self.value;
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
 }
```

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading will run after ViewDidLoad()

SO you ve to set Image in  - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection; only which will run at last when connection didFinish so do like this

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection;
{
    imm = [UIImage imageWithData:self.responseData];
    self.dcp.text = value;
    self.imageview.image = imm;

}
```

Hope Now works...